# Symmetric Economic Curves

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I try to create symmetric curves for the left of the y-axis I get weird results. Does anyone have any idea what to do to get symmetric results?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{???}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw[thick] (0,11) node[left]{$P$}--(0,0)--(12,0) node[below]{$Y$};
\draw[thick] (0,-11) node[left]{$L$}--(0,0)--(12,0);
\draw[thick] (-11,0) node[left]{$W/P$}--(0,0)--(12,0);

\draw (1,8) to [out=280,in=175] (8,1);
\node [right] at (8,1) {$AD(M_0)$};
\draw (3,8) to [out=280,in=175] (8,3);
\node [right] at (8,3) {$AD(M_1)$};
\draw(5,0)--(5,9)node[right]{$AS$};

\node[left] at (0,4.2){$P_1$};
\draw[dotted](0,4.2)--(5,4.2);

\node[left] at (0,1.9){$P_1$};
\draw[dotted](0,1.9)--(5,1.9);

\draw (-1,8) to [out=-0] (-8,1);
\node [left] at (-8,1) {$W_0$};
\draw (-3,8) to [out=0,in=175] (-8,3);
\node [right] at (-8,3) {$W_1)$};
\draw(5,0)--(5,9)node[right]{$AS$};




\foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(5,6)/A, (6,5)/B}
\draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above] {$\PointLabel$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:chart3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: welcome -- please see the answer below  -- in addition you may like to correct the label A and B by editing the syntax --  `\draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[right] {$\PointLabel$};`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mirror something, you can also invoke the *magic mirr—* ...ehm, I mean a `scope` and apply in your case `xscale=-1`.

Then you don't need to calculate anything. Of course whether this approach is convenient or not depends on your case, but for your question is a possible solution.

By the way, I have fixed some of your commands that were redundant, for example you can attach a node to a `\draw` without having to explicitly write it as a separate one.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw[thick] (0,11) node[left]{$P$}--(0,0)--(12,0) node[below]{$Y$};
    \draw[thick] (0,-11) node[left]{$L$}--(0,0)--(12,0);
    \draw[thick] (-11,0) node[left]{$W/P$}--(0,0)--(12,0);
    
    \draw (1,8) to [out=280,in=175] (8,1)
        node[right] {$AD(M_0)$};
    \draw (3,8) to [out=280,in=175] (8,3)
        node[right] {$AD(M_1)$};
    \draw(5,0)--(5,9)node[right]{$AS$};

    \draw[dotted] (0,4.2) -- (5,4.2)
        node[at start, left] {$P_1$};       
    \draw[dotted] (0,1.9) -- (5,1.9)
        node[at start, left] {$P_1$};
    
    % MAGIC MIRROR
    \begin{scope}[xscale=-1]
    \draw (1,8) to [out=280,in=175] (8,1)
        node[left] {$W_0$};
    \draw (3,8) to [out=280,in=175] (8,3)
        node[left] {$W_1$};
    \end{scope}
      
    \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(5,6)/A, (6,5)/B}
    \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above] {$\PointLabel$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it better now -- i have also corrected the label `W1` -- it was misaligned

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw[thick] (0,11) node[left]{$P$}--(0,0)--(12,0) node[below]{$Y$};
    \draw[thick] (0,-11) node[left]{$L$}--(0,0)--(12,0);
    \draw[thick] (-11,0) node[left]{$W/P$}--(0,0)--(12,0);
    
    \draw (1,8) to [out=280,in=175] (8,1);
    \node [right] at (8,1) {$AD(M_0)$};
    \draw (3,8) to [out=280,in=175] (8,3);
    \node [right] at (8,3) {$AD(M_1)$};
    \draw(5,0)--(5,9)node[right]{$AS$};
    
    \node[left] at (0,4.2){$P_1$};
    \draw[dotted](0,4.2)--(5,4.2);
    
    \node[left] at (0,1.9){$P_1$};
    \draw[dotted](0,1.9)--(5,1.9);
    
    \draw (-1,8) to [out=260,in=15] (-8,1);
    \node [left] at (-8,1) {$W_0$};
    \draw (-3,8) to  [out=260,in=15](-8,3);
    \node [below left] at (-8,3) {$W_1$};
    \draw(5,0)--(5,9)node[right]{$AS$};
    
    
    
    
    \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(5,6)/A, (6,5)/B}
    \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above] {$\PointLabel$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```